# Loading in ios indicating with text

Tags: ios, swift, loading

[image]

Please see the attached screenshot, we need the loading in this manner while uploading image or video in IOS Swift

Can you please suggest any one
Thankyou

Comment: Pretty straightforward. When you upload with URLSession, the delegate tells you the progress. So just turn that into text and display it as a label.

Answer (score 1):

So do your upload using an `URLSession` and create an `URLSessionUploadTask`, set yourself as the delegate of the session, and implement the `didSendBodyData` delegate method.

Full method signature:

```
connection(_:didSendBodyData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:)
```

See this thread for more info:

[NSURLSession, upload task - Get actual bytes transferred](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30522793/nsurlsession-upload-task-get-actual-bytes-transferred)

In each call to that method, take totalBytesWritten, format it into a string, and **through a call to the main thread**, update your label text.

(Disclaimer: I haven't done this myself.)